# Error while sniffing packets using "SNIFF" in "SCAPY" (python)

Tags: networking, wireless, python

I wanted to sniff beacon frames from the wireless network.
I installed `scapy` and set the `wlan0` to monitor mode.
then in terminal,

-

1. I entered Scapy command to open scapy.
2. Then in Scapy, I put: `conf.iface="wlan0"`
3. Then I used sniff command as: `p=sniff(count=1)`
4. But it gave me error as:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 561, in sniff
   s = L2socket(type=ETH_P_ALL, *arg, **karg)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 459, in __init__
   self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(type))
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 191, in __init__
   _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
   error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
   ```

Please Help me out. I am trying to use scapy to detect beacon frame from the network.
Also please let me know what should I put in as filter to capture only the beacon frames.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Have you tried using `tcpdump` or a GUI frontend based on it called `Wireshark`. They are very good and versatile AFAIK.

Comment: I know about wireshark, But actually I need to make an application, That's why I want to understand the backend concept of capturing beacon frame.(I want to make a program similar to wireshark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import *

ap_list = []
def myPacketHandler(pkt) :
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) :
        #type 0 = Management subtype 4 = Beacon
        if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 8 :
            if pkt.addr2 not in ap_list :
                ap_list.append(pkt.addr2)
                print "AP MAX: %s with SSID: %s" % (pkt.addr2, pkt.info)

sniff(iface="mon0", prn = myPacketHandler, store=0)
```

**Edit (exit after 500 beacons - can be same beacons):**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import *
import sys

ap_list = []
d = {'counter' : 0}
def myPacketHandler(pkt) :
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) :
        #type 0 = Management subtype 4 = Beacon
        if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 8 :
            d['counter'] += 1
            if d['counter']>500:
                sys.exit()
            if pkt.addr2 not in ap_list :
                ap_list.append(pkt.addr2)
                print "AP MAX: %s with SSID: %s" % (pkt.addr2, pkt.info)

sniff(iface="mon0", prn = myPacketHandler, store=0)
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked and I understood it too. But Just one more thing, when I run this script, it keeps on sniffing indefinitely, Is there a way to stop it after a limit (either using time or count as parameters/ using a keyboard interrupt). Pardon me if its a silly question, as I'm using python for the first time.

Comment: edited:  exit after 500 beacons ...

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that I wasn't using scapy as admin (sudo).
I run the scapy again with sudo and it worked.
Posting the answer to help anyone with similar problem.

But I am still not able to find out what to use as filter.